# Packaging a django app with external dependencies

Tags: django, packaging

I was thinking about packaging one of my django project into a reusable package.

How to package is given quite nicely at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/reusable-apps/ and of course in many other websites.

What all these suggest is to include the re-suable app in your django project's INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py.

Cool, but what I've multiple (3rd party) dependencies to the project. Should I tell in the documentation to include all those packages in the INSTALLED_APPS list!!

I feel that there should be a better way, that you just include one app and all it's dependencies are added to INSTALLED_APPS automatically by the app.

**Now, let me give an example of clarity:** *(you may want to read from here)*

- project A: is a reusable django app
- project B & C: are 3rd party django reusable apps used by project A (django-toolbar, reversion, etc., for example)
- Project D: is your django project, and you want to include my project A in your app.

Now:

- You could add 'A' in your INSTALLED_APPS
- But you also have to add 'B' and 'C' as they are dependencies for 'A'

**My question is:** *Is there a way, by which adding 'A' to your project include 'B' and 'C' automatically?*

That being said, I know how to add custom settings and provide sensible defaults. It's only that, I'm not able to think my head over dependent apps problem (may be it's because it's going to be the next day now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I nailed it with `install_requires` option in setup.py

We also have `tests_require` option and an `extras_require` directive which all goes to `setuptools.setup()` if you are using distribute.

- `install_requires` and `extras_require` both are a list of requirements (packages).
- `extras_require` is a dictionary with 'testing', 'doc' etc., are keys and a list of requirements as list.

These are added into **distribute** in version **`0.5a4`**

Relevant links:

1. [All
   options](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords)
2. [extras_require](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies)

Comment: This is fine for apps that just need to be available for import but if your apps actually need to be listed in INSTALLED_APPS (they contain models, admin classes, template tags etc) then you also need to manually add them. Also - any method to do this automatically would be problematic as sometimes the order of INSTALLED_APPS matters (template overriding or ModelAdmin.register for example)

Answer (score 2):

1. Project A: (with internal app: **c** and external apps: **b**):

   ```
   # Directory Tree:
   A
   ├── setup.py
   ├── a
   │   ├── apps        # internal dependencies
   │   │   ├── c
   │   │   │   ├── models.py
   │   │   │   ├── ...
   │   │   │   ├── app.py
   │   │   │   └── __init__.py
   │   │   └── __init__.py
   │   ├── core        # core library
   │   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   │   └── whatever.py
   │   ├── ...
   │   └── __init__.py # 
   ├── ...
   └── requirements.pip
   ```

   ```
   # File: A/requirements.pip
   # external dependencies: b

   b>=0.1,<0.2
   ```

   ```
   # File: A/setup.py
   setup(
       name="a",
       install_requires=["B",], # External Dependency
       ...
   )
   ```

   ```
   # File: A/a/__init__.py

   # to be added into INSTALLED_APPS later
   CORE_APPS = [
       "B",        # external apps
       "a.apps.C", # internal apps
   ]

   def get_core_apps():
       return CORE_APPS
   ```

   > Project A may be designed as a framework/library without implementation. Thus it does not have `wsgi.py`, `manage.py`, etc.... But Project A could provide an example project (sandbox or demo project).
2. Project D (Django Project): (with app: **a**)

   ```
   # File: D/requirements.pip
   a>=0.1<0.2
   ```

   ```
   # File: D/d/settings.py
   import a
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',

       # ...

   ] + a.get_core_apps()
   ```

   > Project D is an implementation of Project A. Thus it may contains `settings.py`, `wsgi.py`, etc....